# Containerized Quarkus todo application fails to launch properly when deployed on AWS Fargate cluster

Tags: quarkus

I posed this issue already in GitHub, see https://github.com/quarkusio/todo-demo-app/issues/16# but was pointed to here.

I created a Docker image for running quarkus todo list application in DEV mode (ie. usage of H2 data store) using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
LABEL xxx xxx xx@xx
USER root
RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp 
RUN tar xf /tmp/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -C /opt 
RUN ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn 
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/quarkus
COPY quarkus.tar.gz /usr/share/quarkus
RUN tar -xzf /usr/share/quarkus/quarkus.tar.gz -C /usr/share/quarkus
RUN rm -f /usr/share/quarkus/quarkus.tar.gz
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["sh", "-c", "cd /usr/share/quarkus; mvn compile quarkus:dev"]
```

When running this image locally on my Windows docker desktop the application is working fine. The last lines of the console output after start-up are as expected:

```
Hibernate: INSERT INTO todo(id, title, completed, ordering, url) VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), 'Visit Quarkus web site', false, 2, 'https://quarkus.io') Hibernate: INSERT INTO todo(id, title, completed, ordering, url) VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), 'Star Quarkus project', false, 3, 'https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/') 2020-10-24 11:58:57,417 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 0.15.0 started in 3.878s. Listening on: http://[::]:8080 2020-10-24 11:58:57,422 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-validator, jdbc-h2, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jsonb]
```

However this image fails to lauch properly when transferred to Amazon AWS ECR and then deployed there using a ECS Fargate cluster. When opening the application URL via the assigned public IP (http://54.86.53.85:8080/todo.html), the browser just displays a blank page with no content. Nonetheless, the browser tab title of the app is displayed correctly. The last lines of the console output after start-up in this case are:

```
INSERT INTO todo(id, title, completed, ordering, url) VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), 'Introduction to Quarkus', true, 0, null) 2020-10-24 12:11:03 Hibernate: Hibernate: 2020-10-24 12:11:03 2020-10-24 12:11:03 alter table Todo alter table Todo 2020-10-24 12:11:03 add constraint UK_oxfuur9jdyqshux5rm7g7ga6c unique (title) add constraint UK_oxfuur9jdyqshux5rm7g7ga6c unique (title) 2020-10-24 12:11:03 id bigint not null, id bigint not null, 2020-10-24 12:11:03 completed boolean not null, completed boolean not null, 2020-10-24 12:11:03 ordering integer, ordering integer, 2020-10-24 12:11:03 title varchar(255), title varchar(255), 2020-10-24 12:11:03 url varchar(255), url varchar(255), 2020-10-24 12:11:03 primary key (id) primary key (id) 2020-10-24 12:11:03 ) )
```

As can be seen, the message `Listening on: http://[::]:8080` shown at the end of the console output from the locally run image is missing here.

Has anyone an idea idea what goes wrong in the AWS case?

In the ECR Task that is to be created inside the ECS Fargate cluster to run the container, I explictly enabled communication via port 8080. Can it be that special precautions must be taken related to the quarkus todo log mesages `Established TCP socket on 64572` and/or `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`?

I know that native compile mode likely makes more sense here; but I'm still a newbie in the whole area and will keep this as a future option.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue myself by using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11
LABEL xx xx xx@xxx
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/quarkus
COPY quarkus-target.tar.gz /usr/share/quarkus
RUN tar -xzf /usr/share/quarkus/quarkus-target.tar.gz -C /usr/share/quarkus
RUN rm -f /usr/share/quarkus/quarkus-target.tar.gz
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["sh", "-c", "cd /usr/share/quarkus; java -jar target/todo-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar"]
```

Here, `quarkus-target.tar.gz` is a tarball of the target directory after running `mvn package`